# How to scale CGPoints and rescale back in UIView

Tags: ios, swift

My app represent a small ReportReview  I have a custom CanvasView (`UIView`) where the user can draw inside.
When the user will finish the draw will be able to will click the Add `UIButton` and that scribbles will be appended to an object. Each object represent a row in a table.
When the user click any of the rows the colour of the scribbles will be changed on CanvasView to be more visible for user.
When the user finish all the draws can click Save `UIButton` to serialise and save the report as `Data` in CoreData.
The user can review the report deserialising it back.

The problem is that the scribbles are not scaled correctly (I think) and the CGPoints on CanvasView are in different locations.

Here is a link with my small project:
https://github.com/tygruletz/SelectScribblesUsingBinaryData

When I serialise I'm using this function:

```
func serializeDamageItemsTTable(damageItems: [DamageItem], canvas: CanvasView) -> TTable {

    var metaDamage: [TMeta] = []

    metaDamage.append(TMeta(type: .s, name: "descript"))            // DamageItem Name
    metaDamage.append(TMeta(type: .z, name: "scribble"))            // Coordinates for each scribble recorded on the image for DamageItem

    let ttDamageItems = TTable(meta: metaDamage)

    print("SERIALIZATION STARTED")

    damageItems.forEach { damageItem in

        let row = TRow(tMeta: metaDamage)

        row.cell.append(TCell(s: damageItem.name))                  // DamageItem Name

        var scribbleCoord = [UInt8]()

        damageItem.scribbles.forEach { scribble in

            var firstPointInScribble = true
            scribble.forEach { coordinate in

                // ------ Scale all CGPoints ---------
                let factor: CGFloat = 240 / canvas.bounds.width
                let scaledX = UInt8(coordinate.x * factor)
                let scaledY = UInt8(coordinate.y * factor)

                if (coordinate.x > 0 && coordinate.x < 255) && (coordinate.y > 0 && coordinate.y < 127) {
                    scribbleCoord.append(scaledX)                               // Append X coord

                    if firstPointInScribble {
                        firstPointInScribble = false
                        scribbleCoord.append(scaledY | Scribble.yMarkerBitmask) // Append value 1 in front of Y coord + Y coord
                    } else {
                        scribbleCoord.append(scaledY)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        row.cell.append(TCell(data: scribbleCoord))                // Coordinates for each scribble recorded on the image for DamageItem

        print("Damage Item Scribble: \(scribbleCoord)")
        print("SERIALIZATION ENDED")

        do{
            try ttDamageItems.add(row: row)
        } catch{
            print("serializeDamageTTable: Row can't be added: \(error)")
        }
    }
    return ttDamageItems
}
```

When I deserialise I'm using this:

```
// Resize back all CGPoints
    func scaleAllCGPoints(damageItems: [DamageItem], canvas: CanvasView) -> [[CGPoint]] {

        return damageItems.flatMap { damageItem in

            damageItem.scribbles.map { scribble in

                scribble.map { point in
                    let factor: CGFloat = 240 / canvas.bounds.width
                    let scaledX = point.x / factor
                    let scaledY = point.y / factor
                    return CGPoint(x: scaledX, y: scaledY)
                }
            }
        }
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        switch indexPath.section {
        // Cell with the image recorded + scribbles on the image
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reviewCanvasCell", for: indexPath) as! ReviewCanvasCell

            // ------ Resize back all CGPoints ---------
            let scribbleCGPoints = scaleAllCGPoints(damageItems: reviewDamageItems, canvas: cell.reviewCanvas)
            cell.reviewCanvas.currentScribble = scribbleCGPoints

            // ------ Unscaled version ---------
            cell.reviewImageView.image = UIImage(data: report.imageRecorded ?? Data())  // Load Image recorded from CoreData
            cell.reviewCanvas.damageItems = reviewDamageItems                           // Load Scribbles on the image from CoreData
            cell.selectedDamageIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
            return cell

        default: return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }
```

Thanks for reading this !

Comment: For starters, your GitHub repo doesn't match the code you posted in your question. In your project code, you're not scaling any values, so any points greater than `x: 254, y: 126` are being ignored. If you want to save *relative* points for scaling, I'd suggest saving percentages... i.e. `savedX = actualX / canvasWidth` and ``savedY = actualY / canvasHeight`, then pace them back with the inverse.

Comment: Hi @DonMag. I really sorry I just realised that I didn't commit the changes. I implemented your idea and I'm very close to a solution but I have a duplication bug. Please check again the link for project. Here is a screen record: http://g.recordit.co/tH2fNK8Kuz.gif

Comment: Make this: `print("Stroking \(isSelected): \(points)")` the first line in `strokePath(...)` in `CanvasView.swift` --- Start a new report... draw a single, short-as-possible line (so you only have a few points)... Save it... Load it and check debug output. You'll see it's being called twice for that single line, with un-scaled and then scaled coordinates.

Comment: @DonMag I fixed the problem with the position of scribbles. I have another issue which is crashing the app if I draw outside of canvas and I save the report. I need somehow to stop the drawing if the user is going outside of the edges.

Comment: You can avoid that by moving your `let scaledX = UInt8(coordinate.x * factor)` *(and scaledY)* inside the `if (coordinate.x > 0 && ....` block. That will ignore any negative coordinates. I'm confused, though, by your `let factor: CGFloat = 240 / canvas.bounds.width`, which you then use for both X and Y values? Plus, if I put a scribble point below the image - but still within the bounds of the canvas - it re-draws it fine until I save and reload the report... at which point it no longer draws the correct strokes.

Comment: Yes you are perfectly right ! For some reason is displaying me the CGPoints drawn outside of CanvasView.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201545/discussion-between-donmag-and-flo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple needed changes...

Prevent out-of-bounds coordinates. As the user drags to draw a line, if the coordinates go outside the bounds of the "canvas" view, change the x/y to minimum of 0 (zero), and max of bounds.maxX / bounds.maxY

Change the canvas view height to the resulting height of the imageView's Aspect-Fit ratio (in your specific case, the images will always be in `240:127` ratio).